# macro output doesn't work

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++,The macro behavior not as expected.

```
  1     #include<cstdlib>
  2     #include<iostream>
  3     #include<cstring>
  4     #define die(x) std::cout << x << std::endl ; exit(-1) 
  5     const char *help = "Usage: coffee --help --version";
  6     const char *version = "alpha";
  7     int main(int argc,char **argv)
  8     {
  9               if(argc<2||!strcmp(argv[1],"--help"))
 10                       die(help);
 11               if(!strcmp(argv[1],"--version"))
 12                       die(version);
 13 
 14               return 0;
 15               
 16     }
```

---

```
g++ -o sample ./*
./sample --help
```

**Output**:Usage: coffee --help --version

```
./sample --version
```

**Output**:

---

I'm confused why `--version` didn't output string `alpha`.

Comment: A very good sample to demonstrate why its better to use a function definition instead of a macro.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/macros-with-multi-stmts.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `std::cout << x << std::endl ; exit(-1)` is expanded by the macro preoprocessor in these two lines

```
 9               if(argc<2||!strcmp(argv[1],"--help"))
 10                       die(help);
```

the resulting code is:

```
 if(argc<2||!strcmp(argv[1],"--help"))
       std::cout << help << std::endl; 
 exit(-1);
```

Which is probably not what you wanted;

The common trick for "multistatement macros" is to use `do { ... } while(0)` around the statements you want to have in a macro.

You can use `gcc -E` or `cl -E` to get the output from the C preprocessor, so you can see what the compiler ACTUALLY sees.

Edit: I should point out that I personnaly would prefer, in this case, a "die(msg) function" rather than fixing up the macro. Then you can, for example, set a breakpoing in die() and find out how you got there when something isn't working right! You can't set a breakoint in a macro.

Comment: I'm aware of the `do { } while(0)` trick, but can't remember why `{ }` isn't enough. Why is that?

Comment: @configurator: The same reason that `{ }` is _ever_ enough for a multi-line `if` block. Or any block.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Huh?

Comment: `if (x) macro; else ...` will go wrong if you have `#define macro { blah }`.

Comment: @configurator: Good question... _[edit: oh, "isn't". not "is". okay]_

Comment: @configurator [What should be done with macros that have multiple lines](http://parashift.com/c++-faq/macros-with-multi-stmts.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just try to brutally replace the body of the macro and you will see why:

```
if(argc<2||!strcmp(argv[1],"--help"))
  die(help);
```

becomes:

```
if(argc<2||!strcmp(argv[1],"--help"))
  std::cout << help << std::endl;
exit(-1);
```

With no braces `{ }` for the `if` statement, the body is made just of one instruction so the `exit(-1)` is always executed.

You would have discovered if by using an `if / else if` instead that and `if / if` couple since the second `else if` would have missed its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `{ }`. Expand the macro manually and you'll see the result:

```
if(argc<2||!strcmp(argv[1],"--help"))
   std::cout << help << std::endl ; exit(-1);
```

i.e.

```
if(argc<2||!strcmp(argv[1],"--help"))
   std::cout << help << std::endl ;
exit(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code after substitution of macro

```
if(argc<2||!strcmp(argv[1],"--help"))
   std::cout << help << std::endl ; exit(-1) ;  //<-- this exit will work always.
if(!strcmp(argv[1],"--version"))
   std::cout << version << std::endl ; exit(-1) ;
```

correct way:

```
#define die(x) do {std::cout << x << std::endl ; exit(-1); } while(false);
```